# Fastes way to compare single-dimensional against multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364685993
        [memberid] => 131
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364685994
        [memberid] => 133
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1364685995
        [memberid] => 141
    )
)
```

and a single-dimensional array like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => 131
  [1] => 141
  [2] => 191
  [3] => 205
)
```

Now I want to remove all Sub-arrays from multidimensional arrays that DOES NOT contain the memberid value from normal array ?

In this case only Subaray[1] to be removed from multidimensional array as it's 'memberid' key value (133) doesn't show in normal array. Those arrays are actually pretty big, so I am not sure what would be fastest way to do it ?

Comment: Are the arrays coming from a database? If so, do the filtering on the database, not on the client.

Comment: Multidimensional is coming from DB, but other one will be coming from files.

Comment: Then you should probably use the single-dimensional array in the `SELECT` query, using an `IN` clause. E.g. `... memberid IN (131,141,191,205)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would flip the `$nomal` array to get constant lookup time into the array, like this:

```
$normal = array_flip( $normal);
```

Then, you just have to filter the `$multidimensional_array` by the `$normal` array with a simple lookup:

```
$filtered = array_filter( $multidimensional_array, function( $el) use( $normal) {
    return isset( $normal[ $el['member_id'] ]);
});
```

Comment: Dayum, identical solution... :D

Comment: You guys wrote same solution at same time. Thanks to you both. I have to pick only one answer unfortunately, so if you can get mutual agreement that would be nice :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$normalArray = array_flip($normalArray);

$multiDimArray = array_filter($multiDimArray, function ($elem) use ($normalArray) {
    return isset($normalArray[$elem['memberid']]);
});
```

Requires exactly two iterations, one over each array. Key lookups using `$normalArray[$elem['memberId']]` are blazingly fast. May have some memory overhead due to the functional nature and copies of arrays, use a traditional loop and `unset` if that's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have access to development resources at the moment to test but this should work.

```
foreach($members as $member => $property) {
    if (!in_array($property['member_id'], $id_array)) {
        unset($members[$member]);
    }
}
```

`$id_array` is the 1-dimensional matrix (array) you've put in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering the database results after the fact you may want to use the single-dimensional array in the database query itself.

We do not know what the query, you are using, looks like, but something along these lines would  do it:

```
// The ids from the file
$use_ids = array(131, 141, 191, 205);

// Create a list for the IN clause
$ids = '(' . implode(',', $use_ids) . ')';

// Create the query
$query = <<< SQL
    SELECT time, memberid
    FROM some_table
    WHERE ...
        AND memberid IN {$ids}
    ORDER BY time
SQL;

// Execute the query, etc.
```

It is always a good idea to let the SQL handle as much filtering of content as possible.